# Component changes are not showing until app pool is restarted

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, broker

We have this problem with Component Templates with output format: REL and published as Dynamic Component

When we do a content update on the Component, and publish it, the changes don't show up in the Page, so we restart the app pool and after that, the updates are getting reflected

Do I need to do any setting in any of the config file.

Can anyone let me know reason behind this?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? In any case, please leave some feedback so that others who have the same/similar issue can benefit from this question. If you have, provide some additional information based on the suggested answers.

Comment: Hi @AtilaSos,  I wasn't able to read the answers until now, for sure I will my feedback on each answer. So sorry for the delay. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Does this happen for all items or just Component Templates with REL?

Nonetheless, it sounds to me that the cache invalidation is not set up properly or is not working. Tridion has a mechanism (Cache Channel Service) to invalidate the cached items when an item is republished or unpublished. By recycling the app pool, you effectively clear the cache so the new versions of items are retrieved.

More information [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-B69079C3-20A5-4791-AAFB-33DEAB788E38#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-278E2AB0-0B4F-4AC9-B65F-E983C7BAFA90.xml&docid=GUID-7A7921C4-A4F2-44BF-9732-1F358C4E0BDF&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-7A7921C4-A4F2-44BF-9732-1F358C4E0BDF&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DRMI&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1518130809775&currentQuery=RMI&currentScope=) for troubleshooting your scenario.

Comment: it is happening for all items "Published as Dynamic component", after reading tridion documentation, I've updated cache to true (it was set to false), but we are still facing same problem, Content is not updated until we recycle app pool. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that the language of your Publishing Target is not set to 'none'. The 'none' setting will force the publisher to embed the DCPs in the Page, and prevent them from being dynamically included.

Comment: Hi, we have this into tcdl-conf.xml :     
<Properties>
   <Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="dotnet"/></Properties>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related, but on our end we had c# razors being used in component templates and we use to publish the same through Tridion. The issue we had was the way .Net framework works, wherein it used to download the razors for compilation and keeps it in a temp folder after compilation so that they can be used for future. The folder location is

> "%WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\"

So, anytime we published the CT and observed changes weren't reflecting, we had to empty the folder and then it will work. Please note that you need to clear the files under the .net framework version which you are using which in the above example is v4.0.30319

Qualifier, I will like to attach to this is that only when we changed the razors, it used to happen. Not with updating components which were using this component template.